# Rails logging: interpreting which end of API has bad certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, telegram-bot

The following log entry is curious to this viewer:

```
app/controllers/telegram_webhooks_controller.rb:64:in `message'
Started POST "/telegram/[uniq_string]" for 91.108.6.62 at 2022-02-22 10:49:02 +0000
Processing by TelegramWebhooksController#message
  Update: {"update_id":222555282,"message":{"message_id":393,"from":{"id" [...}}}
Responded with message
Completed in 7ms

OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate has expired)):
```

• A webhook receives a request. *note: the webhook was re-verified with result `{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook is already set"}`*

• The webhook controller receives and processes the request with a response message.
• The action is completed
• then an SSL error is raised

Who's certificate would be at fault according to this line of the log?  The application's or the Telegram server's?
*it would be odd that the application's cert were expired, as otherwise the site would not be accessible for all its other functions AND the webhook was set, presumably with the Telegram verifying the cert before doing so.  Even odder that Telegram would operate its server without a cert.*

**Update**  the discussion with @Yan has pointed to a trace of solution.  nginx configurations were reviewed and certs renewed.

```
openssl s_client -connect site.example.online:443 -cert certname
Error opening client certificate private key file certname
49295:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.8.4/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:356:fopen('certname','r')
49295:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.8.4/src/crypto/bio/bss_file.c:358:
unable to load client certificate private key file

$ openssl s_client -connect site.example.online:443 -certform format
CONNECTED(00000003)
49310:error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.8.4/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:593:
```

`openssl version` returns
`OpenSSL 1.1.1f`
Meanwhile, the web pages are being served via https and verifying the data provided through the browser has no red flags.

Comment: Double check the server time where this app is running. It could be off by few minutes and that can cause cert expired error

Comment: Yes, I have checked everything seemed normal, I even set `timedatectl set-ntp yes` on the Ubuntu server.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Try openssl s_client -connect host:port to inspect the cert and see the expiration date / time. It seems the cert issue is on the telegram side or the server you are sending the request to

Comment: Good poke!  Interesting error:  `CONNECTED(00000003)
49130:error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.8.4/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:593:`

Comment: Actually double check your certificate as well. I am not familiar with telegram bots but it’s possible this is error is raised by telegram trying to access the webhook

Comment: Yeah, I actually renewed the cert before re-trying all this to no avail.  But I noticed lets encrypt did not update the site-enabled file as it usually does.  That seems to be the thread to follow.

Comment: Use the same openssl command to inspect your certificate.  The webhook url cert.  you can probably access webhook url in the browser and see if it complains that cert is expired

Comment: question amended with enquiry data

Comment: After updating your certs you are still getting the same `certificate verify failed (certificate has expired)` ?  I am not sure these OpenSSL errors but you can run `penssl s_client -connect web-server:port 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates` and that will show notBefore and notAfter info

Comment: by the way `app/controllers/telegram_webhooks_controller.rb:64` is where you make a request to the telegram server? What is on that line?

Comment: That line has `respond_with :message, text: t('.content', text: message['text'])` thus communicating with T server.  With your suggestion one does see a problem of accessing OpenSSL098  when the version is `OpenSSL 1.1.1f`  as if my user is running one OpenSSL and the system default is being accessed...

Comment: could be old SSL version is used by ruby.  Weird.  if you just run `openssl s_client -connect web-server:port` connecting to the web hook endpoint do you see certificates and they are correct?  Is the error you seeing still expired certs?

Comment: Bingo!  It is finding a cert that was used a while ago, but not the cert that the nginx conf file is pointing to in the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/` So I guess I should empty that directory of cruft...

Comment: directory of cruft is never a good idea :)

Comment: It's a mess in there.  Part is certainly the devOps fault (me!), part the let's encrypt processes.. there are duplicates lying around in there.  warning to anyone who manages to read to this point.